# is it possible to return a value from a function to a function parameter? js

Tags: javascript

so I noticed that when you use `.addEventListener()` you can get its event array like this:

```js
document.getElementById("elementID").addEventListener("click",function(event) {
 console.log(event);
});
```

Is there any way I can create my own function like this? I tried this before but I completely  forgot how I managed to do it.

Right now I am trying

```
function foo(do) {
 let a = 0;
 setTimeout(do,1);
 return a;
}

foo(function(a) {
 console.log(a);
});
```

(results in `undefined`)

Comment: Just because a variable and the parameter of a function have the same name doesn't "connect" them magically. You have to pass `a` to `do()`.

Comment: pass arguments on timeout to `do` by adding them to the setTimeout call - like `setTimeout(do,1, argument1, argument2, ...);`

Comment: @Bravo Okay thank you I will try this!

Comment: don't expect `a` to be changed in `foo` though

Comment: @Bravo I tried this is it still logged `undefined`

Comment: Also, I know that this is only an example, but `foo(do)` won't work as `do` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used for variable names.

Comment: so, you're not getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing formal parameter` - so, I think you're not showing code you're having an issue with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass extra arguments to `setTimeout`, but note that updating the value in the function does not propagate it back (also note `do` is a reserved keyword so I changed the name to `fn`)

```js
function foo(fn) {
 let a = 0;
 setTimeout(fn,1,a);
 return a;
}

const result = foo(function(a) {
 console.log(a);
 a += 1
});

console.log(result);
```

So, you can pass an object in instead, and updating that will indeed propagate the change:

```js
function foo(fn) {
 let a = {value:0};
 //setTimeout(fn,1,a);
 fn(a)
 return a.value;
}

const result = foo(function(a) {
 console.log(a);
 a.value += 1
});

console.log(result);
```

But note that I had to take out the `setTimeout` and replace it with a direct call to `fn(a)` - if I would have left that in, the function would have returned before the call to `fn` was made:

```js
function foo(fn) {
 let a = {value:0};
 setTimeout(fn,1,a);
 return a.value;
}

const result = foo(function(a) {
 console.log(a);
 a.value += 1
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: _"function would have returned before the call to fn was made"_ - at which point you'd probably suggest using promises?

Comment: @evolutionxbox exactly, but I thought that was probably a step too far for this question right now. If the OP wants to see how to make this work I will happily update the answer to show it (perhaps I should anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution:

```
function foo(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var a = 0;
    event(a);
  },1);
}

foo(function(a) {
  console.log(a);
});
```

logs `0`

I forgot to mention that I am using code.org and coding with code.org is very very weird. It won't let you do a lot of really cool things like adding arguments for the `setTimeout`

Comment: You still won't be able to update `a` from inside `event`, nor return from the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I understand that but updating the `a` was not my intention when I wanted to do this.